# Add iOS push notification after app has been submitted to app store

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Is it possible to add push notification to your app after it has been submitted to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Enable the APNS and create new provisioning profile and submit with that. But you should have strong confidence about your coding. Because any how during the review mode if they could found that your push notification is not working then they will reject your app. So better test it first then submit it.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. You just have to enable push notifications for your app ID, create a new provisioning profile that contains the push entitlement and build your app with that provisioning profile. That requires releasing a new version of your app.